# How to add multiple dictionaries which are present inside a list with same keys?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
[{ "a" :1 , "b":2 , "c":3},{ "a" :2 , "b":4 , "c":6},{ "a" :7 , "b":8 , "c":9}]
```

I am trying to create a single dictionary of the keys `a,b,c` and all 3 dictionary values like

```
result = {"a": 10 , "b": 14, "c": 18}`
```

Comment: What language are you trying to do this in, and what's stopping you?

Comment: You can create a new dict and iterate and over list while adding them in new dict.

Comment: I am using python3

Comment: @ShantanuTripathi, please suggest the code for that in python, I am trying for the last 12 hours

Comment: i am trying to do dynamically instead of the static method, but i am stuck with list index out of range error

Answer (score 0):

```py
from collections import defaultdict
arr = [{ "a" :1 , "b":2 , "c":3},{ "a" :2 , "b":4 , "c":6},{ "a" :7 , "b":8 , "c":9}]
d = defaultdict(int)
for dictionary in arr:
    for key in dictionary.keys():
        d[key] += dictionary[key]
print(d)
# d = defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'a': 10, 'b': 14, 'c': 18})
```

Learn more about defaultdict [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/defaultdict-in-python/)

Comment: You could use `Counter` directly :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the result this way, and thanks for answering @Shantanu Tripati

```
data = [{ "a" :1 , "b":2 , "c":3},{ "a" :2 , "b":4 , "c":6},{ "a" :7 , "b":8 , "c":9}]

res = {}
for x in data:
for k, v in x.items():
    if k not in res:
        res[k] = 0
    res[k] += v

In [5]: print(res)                                                                                                                                         
Out[5]: {'a': 10, 'b': 14, 'c': 18}
```